# Find quadrilateral bounding box for detected object

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, object-detection, bounding-box, quadrilaterals

I have been working on a Door detector in an uncontrolled environment. I used mask rcnn with to get the mask and bounding boxes. Though the class accuracy is very good, the mask is not very accurate. Also the expected result is a bounding quadrilateral (get the box connecting the exact 4 corners of the door ) but the bounding box returned is rectangular. I tried taking the mask, finding the convex hull and then simplify the hull using cv2.approxPolyDP to get the quadrilateral. In some cases it's giving great output where the mask is accurate but doesn't work for all specifically when there is an occlusion or the mask obtained is not very uniform around the edges.

Using Oriented Bounding Box detector also gives a rotated rectangle not quadrilateral. I would like to have some suggestion regarding how can I achieve the required result.

TIA

Comment: so you want to *track* that door's corners? then you should try inferring those points

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz Could you please give some pointer on how to do that?

Comment: you should present some data. please review [ask]. do what you can to make it easy to help you. if I have to ask for the most crucial bits of information, this isn't gonna work.